# Interceptor or $stateChangeStart event to redirect to a login page using $location

Tags: angularjs, authentication, routes, angular-ui-router

I am writing an interceptor to redirect to a login page if the user is not yet logged in. I am using $location to change the browser address.

The code works, however, "sometimes" if type a url which is for logged users (e.g: http://localhost:4662/#/index/companies), the browser load the "companies" template and change the url address to the login page: (http://localhost:4662/#/ ). So I have to hit enter to really redirect to login page. It happens sometimes (sometimes means I can do it multiple times and I get the behavior expected but suddenly it doesn't do what is expected)

This is my code:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope, $location, $injector) {

        return {
            request: function (config) {

                //the same config / modified config / a new config needs to be returned.
                var applicationService = $injector.get('applicationService');

                var loggedIn = applicationService.isLoggedIn();
                if (!loggedIn) {
                    $location.path('/');
                    //$window.location.href = "#";
                } else if ($location.path() == '/') {
                    $location.path('/index');                       
                     }

                return config;
            },
           requestError: function (rejection) {......
```

Instead of using interceptor I tried it implementing the route change listener as follows, but I got exactly the same issue:

```
    app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, applicationService){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            var loggedIn = applicationService.isLoggedIn();
            if (!loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/');                    
            } else if (toState.name == 'home') {
                $location.path('/index');
            }
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? I am wondering if $location is not the right option.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when using ui-router you change state programmaticly by using the `go` method of the `$state` object:

```
$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])
```

> Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. $state.go calls $state.transitionTo internally but automatically sets options to { location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the current state.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: $state.go fired another $stateChangeStart event and it ended in a infinite loop.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094273/stop-angular-ui-router-navigation-until-promise-is-resolved/28827077#28827077 although i'de recommend reading the entire question and all of the answers.

Comment: thanks, i found the event.preventDefault() avoided the infinite loop and combined with $state.go produced the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution found is:

```
    app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, applicationService){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            var loggedIn = applicationService.isLoggedIn();

            //Go to home butis logged, redirect to main page (connections)
            if (toState.name == 'home' && loggedIn) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('index');
                return;
            }

            if (toState.name === 'home') {
                // doe she/he try to go to login? - let him/her go
                return;
            }

            if (loggedIn) {
                // is logged in? - can go anyhwere
                return;
            }

            // else, is logged in? No- Go to login
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('home');


        });
    });
```