# UI-Router $stateChangeStart promise function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

As you may already be aware I'm using UI-Router with my AngularJS app. I have a page which accepts user input, lets call it a profile page for this matter. Within this page I have a save button where the user can save the information they inputted. That part works great there are no issues.

What I want to do is save the page/ information on state change. What I was thinking of doing is, within my controller is something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        saveFile();

    });


// Save Document
    function saveFile() {
        $(".page-loading").removeClass("hidden");

        html2canvas($('#main_page'), {
            // When image is rendered proceed with saving the file
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //$rootScope.contentJson.image = canvas.toDataURL();


                var html = $('#main_page')[0].innerHTML;
                for (var x in tmpList) {
                    if (tmpList[x].saveText === 'true') {

                        tmpList[x].element = tmpList[x].savedElement;
                    }
                    if (tmpList[x].saveText === 'tabs') {
                        for (var y in tmpList[x].tabType) {
                            tmpList[x].tabType[y].tabText = tmpList[x].tabType[y].savedElement;
                            tmpList[x].tabType[y].header = tmpList[x].tabType[y].savedHeader;
                        }
                    }
                    if (tmpList[x].saveText === 'table') {
                        for (var y in tmpList[x].layout) {
                            for (var z in tmpList[x].layout[y].row) {
                                tmpList[x].layout[y].row[z].text = tmpList[x].layout[y].row[z].savedText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (tmpList[x].saveText === 'accordion') {

                        for (var y in tmpList[x].accordion) {
                            tmpList[x].accordion[y].title = tmpList[x].accordion[y].savedTitle;
                            tmpList[x].accordion[y].content = tmpList[x].accordion[y].savedContent;
                        }
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    'html': html,
                    'image': canvas.toDataURL(),
                    'json': JSON.stringify({"content": tmpList, "gallery": $scope.img, "audio": $scope.audio})
                };
                editorData.saveContent(data).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.pushAlerts('Saved');
                    $rootScope.lastSegment = '';
                    $(".page-loading").addClass("hidden");


                    // If its a new content
                    if ($rootScope.newElement == 'new-content') {

                        // Set Content ID
                        $rootScope.contentID = response.data.id;

                        // Set cookie for contentID
                        $cookies.put('contentID', $rootScope.contentID);

                        // Set new element to empty
                        $rootScope.newElement = '';
                        $cookies.remove('newElement');

                        // Redirect and populate contentID
                        $state.go('editor', {
                            topicID: $stateParams.topicID,
                            contentID: response.data.id
                        });
                        $state.reload();
                    }

                    var currentTime = new Date();

                    $scope.timeSaved = currentTime.getMinutes();

                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Which in my mind makes sense (maybe it doesn't in yours :) ). But the problem is the saveFile() function doesnt finish and state changes. Has anyone come accross a way for example to wait until this function finishes and only then continue with state change? Maybe create a promise?

Thanks

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094273/stop-angular-ui-router-navigation-until-promise-is-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the state change from happening, save your file, then continue with the state change.

You can also modify your `saveFile()` to return a promise. (Check out [documentation for $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q))

(I've not tested this. There might also be a neater way to only prevent the change on the first stateChange.)

```
var savedFlag = false;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if (!savedFlag) {
    event.preventDefault();

    saveFile().then(function (response) {
      savedFlag = true;
      $state.go(toState, toParams);
    }, function (error) {
      // handle error
    });
  }
});

function saveFile() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  html2canvas(..., {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
        ...
        return deferred.resolve('success!');
     }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```